# PHP 7 OAuthProvider VS random_bytes token generation

Tags: php, security, random, token

My goal is simply to generate a *temporary* token that will be used in URLs for user identification, should I use [`OAuthProvider::generateToken`](http://php.net/manual/en/oauthprovider.generatetoken.php) or [`random_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)?

From these answers :

[Generate a single use token in PHP: random_bytes or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716613/generate-a-single-use-token-in-php-random-bytes-or-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes)

and

[best practice to generate random token for forgot password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910814/best-practice-to-generate-random-token-for-forgot-password)

It seems that `random_bytes` is a more recently updated option for PHP 7 when compared to `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`. Is it the same when compared to `OAuthProvider::generateToken`?

Examples:

```
$rb_token = bin2hex(random_bytes($length));
$oa_token = bin2hex((new OAuthProvider())->generateToken($length, TRUE));
// TRUE = strong "/dev/random will be used for entropy"
```

Comment: Depends on portability, got to install OAuthProvider, random_bytes if you got php7 and openssl is generally available in most deployments, all create random bytes.. are you asking which is more random? Whats random?

Comment: Also forgot password tokens don't need to be cryptographically random.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Are you saying it's ok to be able to guess a password reset token?

Comment: The odds of guessing a sane length nonce token and then correctly entering the email address for that token. It's far easier to just hack the person's email or brute force the account. Also, I didn't say guess, I said does not need to be cryptographically secure. Timing attacks and sidechanel attacks are not a problem with any of the above functions..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone To "crack" a plain prng, the only thing you have to guess is the seed, which for example in c# Random() is 32 bits, in php it's 31 bits (php only uses signed). If you can try 1000 per second, you will have the correct one in 49 days *for sure*, and you have a reasonable chance to have it much earlier. I don't think that's good enough. And 1000/s is a conservative guess for any decent web application.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone As Gabor pointed out, from both possibilities I presented, I'd like to know which method has a lower probability of someone else "guessing" the token and why.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for `random_bytes` (if you use PHP < 7, a polyfill with a good reputations exists, [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat)).
Differences in between `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` are negligible for your case (a more detailed explanation can be found [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324209/when-to-use-dev-random-vs-dev-urandom)).

`random_bytes` use `getrandom` syscall or `/dev/urandom`, ([source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/random.c#L84)), while  `OAuthProvider::generateToken()` without strong mode seems to fallback to some unsecure implementation if the generated string is too short ([source code](http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/web_services/oauth.git;a=blob;f=provider.c;h=0170ee1ad867d9dabc04253ac1074ff641714a87;hb=HEAD#l898), and [source code of `php_mt_rand`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9b89b09b24ffe29c2b6de24c3d9b21df4f2a9de0/ext/standard/mt_rand.c#L163)). So `random_bytes` has a edge over usability (no unsafe mode), and on systems using `getrandom` syscall, as it should be the preferred method ([detailled explanation here](https://lwn.net/Articles/606141/)).

Another way to conclude is to look at some widely-used libraries: FOSOAuthServer bundle, for Symfony applications, [uses `random_bytes`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/be9bece4c47436d72d8cd1c61e18fc67c729d4da/Util/Random.php#L23) too.
Last but not least, I believe some PHP core function will also receive more scrutinity, and better support, than an extension.

Comment: Thank you. Just a quick look at [`OAuthProvider::generateToken()` source](http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/web_services/oauth.git;a=blob;f=provider.c;h=0170ee1ad867d9dabc04253ac1074ff641714a87;hb=HEAD#l898) it seems it also uses `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` when **strong** is used. (Line 934 `fd = open(strong?"/dev/random":"/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);`).

Comment: That's correct, `OAuthProvider::generateToken()` with strong mode and `random_bytes` are almost similar.  Hence my conclusion over ease-of-use, but maybe I should edit my message to make it clearer?